# Distributed execution with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am working on a Robotic process automation where i need to automate 10 different process flows.Robot needs to run 24/7.My solution is hosted in AWS cloud and i have got 10 cloud machines to run the scripts.

I have a master Jenkins job which will retrieve the list of automated jobs to execute from a database and i have 10 different jobs configured in Jenkins server.Number of jobs that i need to run at the same time varies from time to time.It may be N different scripts or N instances of the same script with different data combinations.

Challenge i am facing is in post build action i am not able to control the list of scripts/jobs that i need to run based on the output from Jenkins master job.Is there any way to run only the job i need based on the output from a build command?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using Jenkins Flexible Publish plugin.